# Specifying conditions on a relationship in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, conditional-statements, relationships

I have the following

```
has_many :administrators, :class_name => "User", :conditions => "role_id = 4"
```

and it works fine, but instead of using the foreign key

```
"role_id = 4"
```

I would prefer to specify the actual role string in the roles table, that that foreign key relates to, e.g "Admin"

UPDATE:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u, roles r
WHERE u.role_id = r.id
AND r.role = "Admin"
```

UPDATE 2

can't I do something like this: (this doesn't work, but illustrates what I am trying to do)

```
has_many :administrators, :class_name => "User", :conditions => { :role => {:name => "Admin"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
has_many :administrators, :class_name => "User", :conditions => {:roles => {:name => "Admin"}}, :include => :role
```

Answer (score 0):

what about trying

```
has_many :administrators, :class_name => "User", :conditions => "role_id = #{Role.find(:name => 'Admin')}"
```

Assuming the role table had a corresponding model. are you using a specific framework, or home baked authorization?

Comment: I guess your condition should be a labmda or a Proc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply colinross, so your solution would run a nested query? I am using home baked authorization.

Comment: With the exception of using a set of Class CONSTANTS with the ROLES => ids, no matter how you slice it, you are going to be making a subquery at one point or another if the values are in the database, right?